# Masking in Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

We are using Broadleaf Commerce 3.0.5 version. As we know that , the community version is not having the source code. and Admin is present in jar level. I have a requirement to do a Masking in Admin User Information. Can anybody respose this post , so that I can resolve my issue?

```
Thanks and Regards
--Sitakant
```

Comment: Sitakant, I'm not exactly sure what you are referring to by "Masking". Perhaps you can provide more context of what you are trying to do.

Also, the source for Broadleaf Community is available on Maven central and through Github.

Brian

Disclaimer: I work for Broadleaf Commerce

Comment: @polster: Thanks for Reply. We just wanna to access the Admin Customer Details Data to manipulate it. Can you plz tell me how can we do that ?

Comment: did you checked in database. for tables having details about this admin user?

Comment: @VishnudevK Data are there in Database. How can I handle the same to manipulate as I cann't use its Code for Controller and Service ?

Comment: @SKC... not getting you.

Comment: @VishnudevK : How can I do manipulation on Data in Admin as I don't have access to Service as Well Controller ?

Comment: @SKC...what kind of manipulation are you targeting? From your questions it is not clear what are you exactly looking for. Also, if you want to manually do any change in customer data you can use admin login and see both customer and order details.

Comment: In order Tab of Admin, we are showing the data like 

Customer Name : SKC
Address : Bangalore,Bangalore,India
PIN : 560034

Insead of displaying data in above format,
we need to display

Customer Name : S*C
Address : B******e,B******e,I***a
PIN : 5****4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, all of the source code for the CE version of the Broadleaf Framework is open source and on GitHub at https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce.